# Household Configuration on Spark

Tags: households, civicrm-spark

I am launching a new organization, and CiviCRM Spark looks like a great fit.

I noticed on the "subscription" page that the household configuration is disabled by default. Is it possible to enable that configuration using Spark?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - once you have signed up, you can email spark@civicrm.org and it will be enabled.